# Positioning links next to logo on navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav

Basically what I am doing is trying to get the navigation links to be centered in the middle of the navigation bar. I read up a little that float: left; may affect positioning of divs that are right next to it. So my question is there any solutions to get the navigation links in the middle of the navigation bar?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Navigation Styles */

.nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aeaeae;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo h2 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 70px;
}
.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9595a2;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, text;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .1s, .1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
  -moz-transition-property: color, text;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
  -o-transition-property: color, text;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}
.nav .logo a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.nav-links {
  float: right;
}
.nav-links ul {} .nav-links li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-links a {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #9595a2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* About Styles */

.about {
  height: 880px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
}
.about h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Moises Cortez | Graphic Designer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <h2><a href="#">Moises</a></h2>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tag in HTML are inline elements. To be able to give them margin or padding. You must display block or inline-block to make anchors a block level element.

**CSS**

```
.nav-links a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Add that CSS line to your existing selector.

Comment: Wow it was that simple! Thanks for the quick answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements, you can use **display:table;** and **display:table-cell** to the children elements in the menu. Then add `vertical-align:middle` to each table-cell element. This approach will avoid you any calculation on margin and padding and it will be easy to vertical align each element.

1. I suggest you to create another wrapper inside .nav, called
   `.nav-wrapper`.
2. Set `.nav-wrapper` as `display:table;` with height and width at 100%.
3. Set .nav-link and .logo as `display:table-cell;` `vertical-align:middle;` so to vertical-align both.
4. Remove padding top from the links and display each link as `display:inline-block;`

**CHECK DEMO**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Navigation Styles */

.nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aeaeae;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-wrapper{
  display:table;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.logo{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.logo h2 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 70px;
}
.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9595a2;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, text;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .1s, .1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
  -moz-transition-property: color, text;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
  -o-transition-property: color, text;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}
.nav .logo a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.nav-links {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:right;
}
.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-links a {
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #9595a2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* About Styles */

.about {
  height: 880px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #193047, inset 0 -8px 8px -8px #193047;
}
.about h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Moises Cortez | Graphic Designer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="logo">
        <h2><a href="#">Moises</a></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="about">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So would this solution be better than the one @dowomenfart suggested?

Comment: Far better, because try to inspect the elements in the navigation menu. Everything is naturally aligned without padding or margins :) It's a cleaner solution.

Comment: This is a responsive approach :) The other one isn't because you need to rely on fixed padding or margins .